# Integer solutions to $x^2 - 15 y^2 = 15$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How would one show that $x^2 - 15 y^2 = 15$ has no integer solutions ?

I got that $x = \pm \sqrt{15 (y^2 +1) }$ and then WLOG I assume that $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x = \sqrt{15 (y^2 +1) }$. From there, I want to show that for every $y \in \mathbb{Z}$, $15 (y^2 +1)$ is not a square.

Clearly, $y^2 +1$ is not a square but how do I know that $15(y^2 +1)$ is not one ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: The number $x$ is divisible by $15$ so write $x = 15t$. Then $15t^2 - y^2 = 1$ and that has no solution mod $3$.

Comment: suppose $15(y^2+1)$ square then $y^2+1=15k$ , where $k$ is a square .Which implies $y^2+1\equiv 0(mod\,3),$ contradiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $15(y^2+1)$ is a square then $y^2+1$ is divisible by $15$, so in particular it is divisible by $3$, a contradiction.

Note that your remark

> Clearly, $y^2+1$ is not a square...

is false because $0^2+1=1^2=(-1)^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I meant to say non trivial square of course :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x$ must be divisible by $3$, hence $x^2$ is divisible by $9$. Putting $x=3z$, we have in fact that $5(y^2+1)$ is divisible by $3$, which you can reject by a case distinction on the remainder of $y$ modulo $3$.